# How do I write a locale-aware DateTime sensibly into Spreadsheet::WriteExcel?

Tags: excel, perl, datetime

I have got a [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) object that is in a specific locale (with a [DateTime::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Locale) object attached to it). I want to write a date string to an XLS file using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel), but I want the output that's visible to user of the Excel file to be of the same locale as the one attached to my DateTime object.

There is some [documentation on this matter within Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#DATES-AND-TIME-IN-EXCEL). It's possible to set formats using a combination of a string, [`$wb->add_format()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#add_format(%25properties)) and [`$ws->write_date_time()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#write_date_time($row,-$col,-$date_string,-$format)).

I can get locale information from DateTime via DateTime::Locale by looking at the [CLDR patterns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#CLDR-Patterns). There are also the named formats, which are easier to use. Something like `$locale->date_format_short` is actually quite nice.

```
use DateTime::Locale;

say DateTime::Locale->load('en_GB')->date_format_short; # dd/MM/y
say DateTime::Locale->load('en_US')->date_format_short; # M/d/yy
```

Now the problem with this is, that Excel does not know what a single `y` means. So my workaround has been to just replace a single `y` with `yy`, as that seems to roughly be the same.

Excel also doesn't like upper case letters in the format. I have no idea how it distinguishes between minutes and months, but it works.

This example seems to work, but I am sure it's not perfect.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Locale;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("date_time.xls");
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Write the column headers
$worksheet->write('A1', 'Formatted date');
$worksheet->write('B1', 'Format');
$worksheet->write('C1', 'Locale');

my $row = 0;
for my $locale (qw/en_GB en_US de_DE ko_KR/) {
    $row++;
    my $format_string =
      lc(DateTime::Locale->load($locale)->date_format_short)
      =~ s{
           (?<!y)   #  2. not preceded by a y
           y        # 1. a single y
           (?!y)    #   3. not followed by a y
        }{yy}xr;    #    4. replaced with two y
    my $format = $workbook->add_format(num_format => $format_string);

    $worksheet->write_date_time($row, 0, DateTime->now->datetime, $format);
    $worksheet->write($row, 1, $format_string);
    $worksheet->write($row, 2, $locale);
}
```

This produces the following Excel file.

[image: Screenshot of Excel file with 4 different formats]

They all work, but the code is smelly. Is there something I've overlooked? Maybe someone has written a more correct converter for these format strings that I've not seen yet.

Please note that [DateTime::Format::Excel](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Excel) is not helpful as it only works the other way around, turning Excel dates into DateTime objects.

Comment: This might very well be a little bit off-topic. I'm not really sure how to rephrase it into less of a module recommendation question.

Comment: @martin thanks for that edit! What a blunder. Fancy coming to the [London Perl Workshop](http://act.yapc.eu/lpw2019/) in October for a pint? :)

Comment: The way I see it, the question boils down to: What are the differences between the the formats returned by `$ocale->date_format_short` and those used by Excel (Windows?). If there are more differences, then it might be worth writing a module. If you identified the only difference, then handling like you are is fine. However, a quick look for the former didn't lead to anything.

Comment: Tip: `(?:^|[^y])\K` might be faster than `(?<!y)`. But given the shortness of the strings and the lack of /g, I probably shouldn't have mentioned it :)

Comment: @ikegami I have considered writing a module for this, but as always, checking first is probably a good idea. I'm also not sure what form that module would have. // Windows, most likely. I am talking about the XLS format (although my screenshot is Libre Office on Ubuntu, that's all I have), which is what the product I am working on delivers. Most users for that file would be on Windows.

Comment: By "used by Excel (Windows?)", I meant "used by Excel (which probably simply uses what Windows uses)"

Comment: @simbabque - will try to come along.  A friend of mine used to teach at David Game long ago...